# Center SVG g-element dynamically

Tags: html, svg

I want to center a `g` (group) element in my svg tag. The size of the group is changing by its content.

**Is there an easier way to center the `g`  as to calculate the `x` position depending on the actual size and to translate the element.**

Comment: Not possible without calculation/repositioning, SVG is not meant to work as a layout system.